# Authorization curl php in some site

Tags: php, curl

I have some task.
I need to authorization in site via curl
but all what I used - wrong.

Please show me how it fix.
Because I need to work  with this site.
Thanks!

Comment: are you definately doing authentication via post on the login page or do it accept httpd authentication ? also I assume your postfields in are actually called username and password so your string should be username= not login[username]= etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to grab a page first to get some cookie information then login.  I have used your credentials and tested the code below and I logged in ok.  Hopefully you will be able to understand what I have done.

Without the initial curl request to 'http://www.kinguin.net/customer/account/login' I was getting a cookie required landing page.  Once I curled this page then I could log in.

Also, the login page I used was the one that the actual login form posts to ('http://www.kinguin.net/customer/account/loginPost/') and not the one in your question.

```
$firsturl = 'http://www.kinguin.net/customer/account/login';

$ch = curl_init();
$useragent="Fake Mozilla 5.0 ";
$cookie_jar = tempnam ("/tmp", "kinguin");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $firsturl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_jar);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_jar);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$redir = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
curl_close($ch);


$loginurl = 'http://www.kinguin.net/customer/account/loginPost/';
$fields = array('login[username]' => urlencode('dan-ver@ukr.net'),'login[password]' => urlencode    ('78955123'));

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_jar);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_jar);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$redir = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```